# how to sent a SMTP email with a Unicode sender name

Tags: c#, smtp

I'm trying to send an email using a smtp client with a unicode sender name.
I tried to add the sender header like that:

```
 message.AddHeader("Sender", String.Format("{0} <{1}>", Name, email));
```

I get "???????" instead of the sender name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Name);
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    message.AddHeader('Sender', String.Format("=?UTF-8?B?{0}?= <{1}>", base64, email));
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to include an explanation as to why your code changes answer the question.